# Unable to generate WAAD Application Keys

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Recently I no longer been able to generate application keys in WAAD...(or to be more specific I can generate the key but I never get to see the value)

[image]

and after save I receive unauthorized access error...

[image]

I am a directory co-administrator - The key does appear to save, as after a page refresh there is an extra entry into the keys table. Currently only the directory full administrator can see the value but now no-longer co-admins.

The above issues also happens when making modifications to "permissions to other applications", azure reports unauthorized but the changes I make are again committed.

I have ruled out different browsers, have tired IE, and Chrome.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was...

"Users may give applications permission to access their data" was set to "No"

Changing this back to "Yes" then allowed me to generate and see the key values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

co administrator is a subscription role not an Azure AD role.

In order to perform this you should have admin privileges in the Azure AD on which you're trying to create the keys.

What is the Azure AD role you're currently in ?

Comment: Just a "User" - however I have always been just a "User" in the directory.

Comment: There is a configuration option in AAD to allow or prevent non-admin users from maintaining app configurations.  It's possible your administrator has changed this setting.

Comment: So im guessing these are "Users may give applications permission to access their data" and "Users may add integrated applications" under the "Configure" tab of the directory. I will speak to the global admin of the directory and report back.

Comment: Do we have an article that details the impact the of turning these values on\off. We just want to understand the security implications by leaving this value on.